# txt comparison and analysis tool

Tags: gui, log-analysis

I'm looking for a software that can:

1. take a txt file (with the general structure of config file) as an input.
2. extract some variables from the text. eg. one of the lines could be "max allowed connections = 5". This would then need to be accessible as a variable for point 3.
3. Do some simple logical operations on these variables which you can configure yourself
4. show all of this in a GUI
5. Is actively maintained

I recon this sounds like something from a coding 101, but it's for a company that needs to check config and hardware documentation files for certain criteria. We've previously coded the software ourselves, but I'm hoping to not have to maintain it and I'm thinking there must be something out there

EDIT: clarify point 1 and 2

Comment: The "extracts some variables" thing requires imho some clarification. What? How?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica good point, I'll make an edit.